# What's the RegEx to make sure that delimiters are escaped?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that will check whether or not delimiters in a string are  escaped with a backward slash.

The delimiters I am concerned about are comma (\,), colon (\:), semicolon (\;) and of course the backward slash itself has to be escaped (\).

For example, the string "test" should return a match because there are no delimiters in it, and no escaping is necessary. The string "te\;st" would return a match because the semicolon delimiter is escaped. "te;st" and "t\;s:t" would both fail because the both contain at least one delimiter that is not escaped.

I know that I need a conditional and a positive look behind, and this is what I have so far, but it is not giving me the expected answer.

```
^(?<delimiter>[:;,\\])?(?(delimiter)\(?<=(?:\\\\)*\\)k<delimiter>|.)$
```

Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^(?:[^,:;\\]|\\.)*$
```

```
^           # beginning of string
(?:  )*     # 0 or more of:
  [^,:;\\]  #  a normal (non-delimiter) character
|           # or:
  \\.       #  an escaped character (backslash + any)
$           # end of string
```

That is, every piece of the string must be either escaped or a non-delimiter character.

Comment: Derp. It werks. If I try to understand how, my head hurts, but it works. Thank you melpomeme!

Comment: Man that is slick. The |\\. threw me, because I thought it would require everything to be escaped, but now that I see your explanation, I remember that's how regular expressions work. They look for a match, not a non-match. Kudos for doing this without a look behind.

Comment: Melpomene, it looks like the one thing that breaks your regular expression is "te\st". That returns a match because of the `|\\.` when it should fail. Note that it still works with an unescaped backslash at the end of the string "test\". I'm looking now to see if this can be made to work correctly to ensure that backslashes are also escaped.

Comment: I think this solves the problem of needing to not match single backward slashes. `^(?:[^,:;\\]|\\[,:;\\])*$`